# How do I validate what I input?

Tags: java

This is what I need to achieve:

The user can try to input a valid license plate. The valid license plate must be in the following format:
[XXXX][YYY]
Where X is a number between 0 and 9 and Y is an alphabet between A and Z. The user can input word ‘random’ (case insensitive). After that, the program will generate a new random valid license plate.

This is my current code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) 
    System.out.println("");  
String plat = "";  
do { 
    System.out.print("License Plate Format: XXXXYYY "); 
    plat = scan.nextLine();  
    for (int i = 0; i < plate.size(); i++) {
        if(plat.matches(plate.get(i)))  { 
            System.out.println("not unique!"); 
            scan.nextLine();  plat = " "; break; 
        }  
    } 
while (plat.length() < 7 ); 
plate.add(plat);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Regular expressions, loops, parsing?

Comment: I'm really new to java so I'm not too sure, but I already got these down @tibetiroka 
`case 1:
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
System.out.println("");

String plat = "";

do {
System.out.print("License Plate Format: XXXXYYY ");
plat = scan.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < plate.size(); i++) {
if(plat.matches(plate.get(i)))
 {
System.out.println("not unique!");
scan.nextLine();

plat = " ";
break;
}

} while (plat.length() < 7 );
plate.add(plat);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for input validation ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).
For this particular task,assuming the plate must have upper case characters, you can match the input with this regular expression to perform validation.

```java
// assuming input is a String and it is already defined
if (input.matches("[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}")) {
 return "Plate valid";
} else {
 return "Plate invalid";
}
```

This regular expression explicitly tells java to look for strings formed by 4 digits followed by 3 characters.

Answer (score 1):

The code below handles the logic that you need:

- isValidPlate checks whether a plate received as input is valid
- exists checks whether a plate value already existed
- processCommand is the command processer

I have not implemented the randomizer for you. The basic idea for that would be to compute some way you could randomize a plate and call it until it's new.

```
private List<String> plates = new ArrayList<String>();

//...

public boolean isValidPlate(String plate) {
    return plate.matches("[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}");
}

public boolean exists(String plate) {
    return plates.indexOf(plate) > -1;
}

public void processCommand(String plate) {
    if (plate.length() == 6 || plate.length() == 7) {
        if (isValidPlate(plate)) {
            if (!exists(plate)) {
                plates.add(plate);
            } else {
                //maybe do something if the plate already existed
            }
            //maybe do something further with a valid plate given as input
        } else if (plate.equalsIgnoreCase("random")) {
            String newPlate = "";
            //generate a valid plate that does not exist yet and store it into newPlate
            plates.add(newPlate);
            //Do something further
        }
    } else {
        //invalid input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Scanner called scan for input:

```
String plate=scan.nextLine();
if("random".equals(plate)){//generate new
}
else{
    if(plate.length()!=7){//invalid size
    }
    String digits=plate.substring(0,4);
    if(!digits.matches("[0-9]+")){//checks if your string is made of digits using regex
    //invalid
    }
    String letters=plate.substring(4);
    if(!digits.matches("[A-Z]+")){//checks if your string is made of uppercase characters
    //invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to use a single regex to validate the whole string including its length?

Comment: It would be, but I'm not very good with regex, and this version is easier to understand

Comment: I need to use for loop so when it's wrong it'll tell you to input it again. I tried to make it like this but it still takes anything I input disregarding the while 
'do {
System.out.print("License Plate Format: XXXXYYY ");
plat = scan.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < plate.size(); i++) {
if (plat.matches(plate.get(i))) {
System.out.println("This license plate is already registered!");
scan.nextLine();
plat = " ";
break;
}
}
} 
   while (plat.matches("[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}"));
   plate.add(plat);
   System.out.println("License plate registered!");
   scan.nextLine();
   break;
'

Comment: Just check plat.contains(plate) This will tell you if the plate is already registered.